# Opening a url into a split panel using google closure library

Tags: javascript, google-closure, google-closure-library

This solution **must** use the google closure javascript library and not any other javascript library.

When a url loads I would like to dynamically open a split panel where one side contains the content of the url in an iframe and the other side contains logging information about what actions are taking place.

Below is the general setup for the split panel using the google closure library, but i'm unsure how to add the iframe and set its source to the current page url.

```
var lhs = new goog.ui.Component();
var rhs = new goog.ui.Component();

// Set up splitpane with already existing DOM.
var splitpane1 = new goog.ui.SplitPane(lhs, rhs,
    goog.ui.SplitPane.Orientation.HORIZONTAL);

// Need to create an iframe with src of current url and add that to the rhs element.
```

Comment: And you have to use a library for this?

Comment: I don't _have_ to use a library but it hides any browser specific issues that I would normally have to worry about.  (I'll glady pay the abstraction tax in order for it to work correctly in ie6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you render the component, you should be able to just fetch the underlying element and do whatever it is that you need to. Something like:

```
var iframe = goog.dom.createDom('iframe', { 'src': 'rhs.html' });
rhs.getElement().appendChild(iframe);
```